# Finding the length of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to find the length of an array of "header" structures that I defined (a header just holds a few informational int members, if that is relevant here). I attempt this by passing `fl`,  the pointer to the start of the array, and `idx`, an index value that indicates where the proper `fl_tails` pointer is that is stationed at the end of the array (in other/repetitive words, 'fl_tails[idx]` is the pointer to the end):

```
int arr_size(header* fl, int idx){

  int cnt = 1; /* Anything passed guaranteed to have at least 1 */ 

  while(fl != fl_tails[idx]){
    fl++; 
    cnt++;
  }
}
```

I thought this would just advance the `fl` pointer and generate the count properly until the end was reached, but it goes into an infinite loop. I'm wondering if this is caused by something in this function or just something elsewhere that I need to find. When I printed the addresses of the beginning and end as unsigned ints, they seemed innocuous enough---things like 16777216 and 16777344, respectively. Maybe something is also wrong with my understanding of the `header` structure and its size/effect on steps?

Comment: If you already have the index to the last element of the array. The length of the array is simply `index+1`, Why do you need to iterate through the array again?

Comment: That is a different kind of index from a separate array.

Comment: For C it is problematic to find the size of a plain old C array after it has degraded into a pointer (i.e. you have passed it to a function).  Typically you would track the number of elements for the array, or the total size of the array, and pass this into any function that manipulates the array.

Comment: Please show us how `fl_tails` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare addresses, so:

```
while(fl != &fl_tails[idx])
            ^
```

Comment: fl_tails[idx] is itself a pointer (basically an address when considered as a value, right?). When I tried this, I first got a warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default], which went away when I casted fl_tails[idx] to a header pointer (which it already is, strangely enough). But still, this gives me an enormous and incorrect number.

Comment: So fl_tails is not of type 'header*'? For this to work 'fl' must arrive at &fl_tails[idx]. However, even if this worked, it is very fragile as there is nothing guaranteeing that a sensible relationship between fl and fl_tails is passed into this function.

Comment: @nicole, post more code on what `fl_tails` and `fl` are, their declaration etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at your while loop, you're comparing a memory address against a value at an index. This will always evaluate to true. I believe this is why you're getting the infinite loop.

As for the length of the array, have you considered using the sizeof() operator/function.

Comment: But if the 'value' at the index is a pointer, isn't it still an address? `fl_tails` is declared as `header** fl_tails`

Comment: One star * and ** have different meanings in C Pointers. Thats why people are scared of pointers. All I'm saying is you're comparing two different addresses (if that value at the index is an adress).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `fl_tails[idx]` returns a different pointer type and `fl` is of a different pointer type. They will never point to the same location(unless they're inside a union) and so, I think, the program goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that:

```
 while(fl != fl_tails[idx])
```

is equivalent to:

```
 while(fl != *(fl_tails + idx))
```

so what you are doing is comparing a pointer fl to an actual value since (fl_tails + idx) is a pointer and *(fl_tails + idx) is dereferencing this pointer to get the value it is pointing to.

so if you are just comparing pointer addresses to find the end of the array, I would change to:

```
while(fl != &fl_tails[idx])
```

so that you are comparing pointers to pointers.

As far as the values you got, remember that a pointer without a pointee can have a pointee holding an initialized value (some old value from some old program). I recommend seeing this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-pJlnpkLp0